# Getting A Count of Distinct Entities Using Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I'm trying to incorporate Magical Record into my project and I'm liking it a lot, but one thing I am having trouble figuring out how to do is to fetch a count of a request. I know you can execute a fetch request, but as far as I can tell Magical Record has no means of performing a count on one. The reason I feel it has to be a request is because I only want the count of distinct objects.

Does anyone know of a way to do this efficiently? i.e. in a way that doesn't require me to actually perform a fetch on the objects and take the count of the resulting array. It's imperative that this fetch run as quickly as possible as it has the potential of being called fairly often.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at the class methods:

```
+ (NSNumber *) MR_numberOfEntities;
+ (NSNumber *) MR_numberOfEntitiesWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (NSNumber *) MR_numberOfEntitiesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchTerm;
+ (NSNumber *) MR_numberOfEntitiesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchTerm inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

+ (NSUInteger) MR_countOfEntities;
+ (NSUInteger) MR_countOfEntitiesWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (NSUInteger) MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchFilter;
+ (NSUInteger) MR_countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchFilter inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

Comment: Yes, I have.... none of those take in a fetchrequest nor do they offer any way I can think of specifying that I would only want distinct records.

Comment: Then I would say you want to create a variation of each of these methods (count and number), say, countOfUniqueEntities, and numberofUniqieEntities.  These variations should be simple to create given the pattern in the source for these methods.